# NSLocalNotifications with core location

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, uilocalnotification

I tried setting up this feature where user gets a notifications every time the distance between an event that occur in a local JSON file and his current location is < 100 meter asking him whether he is at that event or not , when he presses on yes then that event will be marked as attended. Anyway i tested it on my iPhone and what happened is when i arrived to an event location it kept sending unstoppable notifications (repeatedly) and when i try to press yes or no nothing actually happen it keeps sending these notifications. Can anyone plzz explain for me what could be going wrong ??
 I'm not very familiar with Xcode and objective-C language so i would really appreciate any help.

Comment: How can we tell when you don't post any relevant code?

Comment: ooh I apologise. I forgot to mention that u will find the code in my previous question which has not been answered by anyone.

Comment: @MartinH ooh I apologise. I forgot to mention that u will find the code in my previous question which has not been answered by anyone.

Comment: If your previous question hasn't been answered then you should improve that question.  Post the same question again is not the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using UILocalNotification with core location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367112/using-uilocalnotification-with-core-location)

Comment: How do you actually implement this? Using region monitoring with 100 meter radius? If it is, you will need a flag when the user enters the region, take away the flag when the user exits the region. Share some code for us to help you.